# iTunes U style download/progress/stop/play button

Tags: iphone, ios, download, progress

iTunes U for the iPhone has these wonderful buttons that show

- the download progress
- the stop button and the
- play button (well, the "i" button)

in one place - see attached screenshot. Is this a system icon which can be called by code, or is it something thats not available for developers?

Anyhow: if someone has a source, that describes how to get such kind of buttons, I'd be very happy. It's clear to me, that the icons are controlled by a state-pattern in view-controller.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is DACircularProgress on github, it looks just like the circular progress bar on the Facebook app, I think you can take that, modify it to put the stop button on top and change the color and use it. check it out:

[DACircularProgress](https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress)

Comment: would you mind sharing the control if you did it?

iOS developers around the world would be deeply grateful

Comment: I didn't do it but you can get it by clicking the link in my post.